# Submit form to a friendly URL

Tags: html, forms, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have an autocomplete input

```
<form action='/home.php' method="get">
    <input type="text" name="first" />
</form>
```

When `ENTER` is pressed, form submits itself. I want to use `Apache mod_rewrite` for `home.php?`. This is my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^community/([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$ home.php?first=$1 [L]
```

How i am gonna post my form  to `community/first` instead of `home.php?first=first`?

Comment: change the form method to "POST", and add [QSA] to the end of the Rewrite Rule

Comment: @circusdei It posted it however my url shows like `community/` i want it like `community/first`

Comment: Where does the "First" part come from, and is it variable?

Comment: its value of the `text`. It posts like `home.php?first=first`

Comment: You'll need to change the form action to the "community/first" URL.  If this URL changes based upon the users input, then you'll need some JS to change the form's action based on the input.  Not sure why you'd want this though.

Comment: This is JS question not mod_rewrite one